# select Pandas Dataframe rows with for-loop for different substrings in index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with an index:

```
               A         B         C         D
flowers blue  0.714550  0.208125 -0.216861  good
trucks red   -0.950056  1.779076  0.489394  average    
flowers red   0.249905  0.852931 -0.226787  bad
trucks blue   1.183972  1.120614  0.085162  good
```

Now I want to select all rows containing the substrings I am looking for with the follwing function:

```
def select(df, substring):
    """Select by substring from Dataframe"""    
    for i in substring:
        return df[df.index.to_series().str.contains(i)]
```

If I try:

```
select(df, ['flowers', 'trucks'])
```

it just returns the data selection for the first iteration (flowers).

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Why don't you do `df.loc[df.index.to_series().str.contains(['flowers', 'trucks'])]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the function on the first iteration itself so it never gets to the 'trucks' argument.

You need something like

```
def select(df, substring):
    """Select by substring from Dataframe"""
    frames = []    
    for i in substring:
        frames.append(df[df.index.to_series().str.contains(i)])
    return pd.concat(frames)
```

Though the above function can return the rows in a different order than they occur in the dataframe.

I'd use something like

```
def select(df, substring):
    return df[df.index.to_series().str.contains("|".join(substring))]
```

Here we're passing multiple substring arguments separated by the pipe operator like `flowers|trucks`

Comment: Cheers. Exactly what I was looking for.